# Using Phoenix Channels Cross Origin

Tags: websocket, socket.io, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I currently have an application that is using the Pusher API to enable real time messaging and would like to remove my dependency on Pusher.

I am keen to keep my current application as it stands and connect over websockets to a channel on an Phoenix app that is a completely separate application on a separate instance.  Reasoning for this is it will allow me to separately scale the phoenix app when there is a large number of messages.

Is this possible? I have experience of using Socket.IO and this supports this functionality by specifying the location of the Socket application when trying to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it's possible, you can set the option `:check_origin` as explained in `lib/phoenix/transports/long_poll.ex` source code:

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/transports/long_poll.ex#L26

> - `:check_origin` - if we should check the origin of requests when the
>       origin header is present. It defaults to true and, in such cases,
>       it will check against the host value in `YourApp.Endpoint.config(:url)[:host]`.
>       It may be set to `false` (not recommended) or to a list of explicitly
>       allowed origins